# golang with thrift does not implement thrift.TProcessorFunction (wrong type for Process method)

Tags: go, thrift

I am getting this error:

```
# metric_system
./metric_system.go:227: cannot use myStructProviderProcessorGetMyStruct literal (type *myStructProviderProcessorGetMyStruct) as type thrift.TProcessorFunction in assignment:
    *myStructProviderProcessorGetMyStruct does not implement thrift.TProcessorFunction (wrong type for Process method)
        have Process(int32, thrift.TProtocol, thrift.TProtocol) (bool, thrift.TException)
        want Process(context.Context, int32, thrift.TProtocol, thrift.TProtocol) (bool, thrift.TException)
./metric_system.go:235: not enough arguments in call to processor.Process
    have (int32, thrift.TProtocol, thrift.TProtocol)
    want (context.Context, int32, thrift.TProtocol, thrift.TProtocol)
```

when I am building simple go app using golang 1.8.3 and thrift 0.10.0
To reproduce:

```
2038  thrift -r --gen go metric_system.thrift 
2040  cp -r gen-go/* src
2041  cd src
 2042  go build
```

folder structure

```
./metric_system.thrift
./.settings
./.settings/language.settings.xml
./src
./src/metric_system
./src/metric_system/my_struct_provider-remote
./src/metric_system/my_struct_provider-remote/my_struct_provider-remote.go
./src/metric_system/metric_system.go
./src/metric_system/GoUnusedProtection__.go
./src/metric_system/metric_system-consts.go
./src/main.go
./.cproject
./pkg
./pkg/linux_amd64
./.project
./bin
./gen-go
./gen-go/metric_system
./gen-go/metric_system/my_struct_provider-remote
./gen-go/metric_system/my_struct_provider-remote/my_struct_provider-remote.go
./gen-go/metric_system/metric_system.go
./gen-go/metric_system/GoUnusedProtection__.go
./gen-go/metric_system/metric_system-consts.go
```

metric_system.thrift file:

```
struct MyStruct { 
    1: i64 myInt, 
}

service MyStructProvider { MyStruct getMyStruct() }
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: and metric_system.thrift file looks like this: struct MyStruct {
 1: i64 myInt,
}

service MyStructProvider {
 MyStruct getMyStruct(),
}

Comment: When posting about an issue, it's helpful to include the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all, the `Process` method you've implemented does not meet the interface requirement. You're missing the first argument, a `context.Context`.

Answer (score 0):

switch your git branch to 0.10.0

`$GOPATH:git.apache.org/thrift.git/lib/go/thrift`

`thrift.git git:(master) ✗ git branch -a
  master
  remotes/origin/0.1.x
* remotes/origin/0.10.0
  remotes/origin/0.2.x
  remotes/origin/0.3.x
  remotes/origin/0.4.x
  remotes/origin/0.5.x
  remotes/origin/0.6.x
  remotes/origin/0.7.x
  remotes/origin/0.8.x
  remotes/origin/0.9.1
  remotes/origin/0.9.2
  remotes/origin/0.9.3
  remotes/origin/0.9.x
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/py-compiler`

Answer (score 0):

I sloved this problem by using the master branch of thrift to genergate go code.
https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

the reason is your thrift version is different ， maybe you compile the thrift protocol using 0.9.2 version， but include the  thrift library file is 1.0.0 version